# Error Code: 1052 - Column 'idk' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql

Hi I trying to create query and add this, query error:

```
JOIN matakuliah ON nilai.idk = matakuliah.idk
WHERE matakuliah.semester = 1
```

full query:

```
SET @sql_dinamis = ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT( 'max( IF(idk = ', idk, ',huruf,null) ) AS A', idk ) ) FROM nilai  );

SET @SQL = CONCAT( 'SELECT mahasiswa.nim, mahasiswa.nama, ', @sql_dinamis, ' 
FROM nilai
JOIN mahasiswa ON nilai.idm = mahasiswa.idm
JOIN matakuliah ON nilai.idk = matakuliah.idk
WHERE matakuliah.semester = 1
GROUP BY nilai.idm' );
PREPARE stmt 
FROM
@SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

error message:

```
FROM nilai
JOIN mahasiswa ON nilai.idm = mahasiswa.idm
JOIN matakuliah ON nilai.idk = matakuliah.idk
WHERE matakuliah.semester = 1
GROUP BY nilai.idm' )
> OK
> Time: 0s


PREPARE stmt 
FROM
@SQL
> 1052 - Column 'idk' in field list is ambiguous
> Time: 0s
```

help me to solve this.

this my database https://irhas.online/test/test2.txt please help me.

Comment: IF(idk = ', idk, ',huruf,null) ) AS A', idk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has a reference to `idk` (from the `@sql_dinamis` part) however both your `nilai` and `matakuliah` have `idk` fields in them, so SQL doesn't know which one you want. You need to change the `idk` in

```
SET @sql_dinamis = ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT( 'max( IF(idk = ', idk, ',huruf,null) ) AS A', idk ) ) FROM nilai  );
```

to be either `nilai.idk` or `matakuliah.idk` e.g.

```
SET @sql_dinamis = ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT( 'max( IF(nilai.idk = ', idk, ',huruf,null) ) AS A', idk ) ) FROM nilai  );
```

This works for me (see [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2bA7StrBpz18tLFgAQh2QV/1))

Comment: If this solved your problem it would be helpful to other users if you marked it accepted. If it didn't, provide some feedback in a comment and I will see if I can help more.

Comment: Try my edited answer. I created a DBFiddle and it seems to work fine with the data your provided.

Comment: how to create query:  
  ->when i run query filter semester 1
result not this https://prnt.sc/j9c4gk
but like this https://prnt.sc/j9c4s8
and   
  ->when i run query filter semester 2
result not this https://prnt.sc/j9c56g
but like this https://prnt.sc/j9c5l0

Comment: Try this for your sql_dinamis: `SET @sql_dinamis = ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT CONCAT( 'max( IF(nilai.idk = ', nilai.idk, ',huruf,null) ) AS A', nilai.idk ) ) FROM matakuliah JOIN nilai on matakuliah.idk = nilai.idk where matakuliah.semester='1' )` just replace the semester number as required. I think it does what you asked for.